# Unlinking Path Groups in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, path

I have the following set of social icons as an AI file http://s-icons.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/icon_sets/social_media_icons_pen_sketch_icons_set/social_media_icons_pen_sketch_icons_set.ai.zip

[image: Icon Set]

I wish to create an Instagram Icon by duplicating the Vine Icon (or any other) and embedding the Instagram logo instead. Any ideas how to do this?

OR

If it is not possible how can I re-create my own scribble background?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[image: example 1]
**Multicolour example**

1.First take your scribble background and make sure you have it as outlines.

2. Make sure your logo is all grouped together.
3. Place your scribble path over the top of the logo (Object > Arrange > Bring to Front.
4. Object > Clipping Path > Make (Apple 7 or Control 7)

[image: example 2]
**Single colour example**

Same as above but start with a compound path instead of a group of objects. You can then start to use the pen tool to redraw sections of your mask to make it look more organic by adding and moving points.

*Please excuse the crude diagrams :(*

**Scribble Background**
1. Make an artboard the size of the square you would like.

2. Use the pen or pencil tool to draw joined up vertical lines while staying inside the artboard.
3. Duplicate and rotate your lines 90 degrees (or draw horizontal ones for more random looking effect).
4. Change stroke to the correct colour.

Comment: Thanks for this great tutorial Stevie. Just one thing. As I want to get the same kind of scribbles as in the AI example is it possible to reverse Step 4 in the AI file and then replace with my own logo?

Comment: I just double checked the file and it does not look like it's possible to reverse the step 4 as they have cut into the scribbles (
http://i.imgur.com/p5YNzid.png). I think the best thing would be to redraw the scribbles yourself. It should only take a few minutes to do.